# PHP FTP Loop uploads intermittent files

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I am using pluploader to upload files to the server and then also upload these to an FTP server using ftp_put.

If I upload 1 file at a time it works great, I have tested a 4GB file and that uploaded fine without a problem.

However, the problem comes when uploading multiple files and all the files sizes are the same as the first one once uploaded to the FTP Server.

The code I have is as follows:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $file2; $x++) {

    echo "File Name Is: ";
    echo $filename;

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftpsv) or die("Could not connect to $ftpsv");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $uname, $password);


// upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remotedirectory, $localdirectory, FTP_BINARY))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);

}
```

Note: $remotedirectory and $localdirectory combine 2 variables the folder and the filename.

I have also tried FTP_ASCII and ftp passive mode but still get the same problem.

Thanks in advanced for your help.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why keep opening/closing `$ftp_conn` inside the loop?

Comment: I can take the $ftp_conn outside of loop not a problem no real reason for it being inside loop. But problem is following I upload 2 or more files all file sizes will be same as the first file size e.g. if first file is 1mb all other files after upload will be 1mb regardless of their size. Thanks

Comment: See if they have identical content remotely. I suspect `$local_directory` is not being updated properly in the loop, so it might be updating the same local file to different remote filenames. Can you post code for those variables since it is omitted here?

Comment: Mike, Thanks for the suggestion and you were right. The problem was that $localdirectory combined 2 variables the directory and the filename, but the filename variable was to the test one I had which only saved to the first file, changed this to the correct variable and it's all working now.